# Ошибка: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php

Добрый вечер, подскажите, что тут за ошибка и как исправить?

> `Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in \WWW\sys\inc\fnc.php on line 103`

Строка 103

```
if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `visit_everyday` WHERE `time` = '$last_day'"),0)==0){
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visit_everyday WHERE time = '$last_day'");
if ($result && mysql_result($result, 0) == 0) {
    //do something
}
```

Вот так примерно надо..

Answer (score 1):

В запросе ошибка так или иначе - поэтому возвращается не значение, а `False` (тот самый `Boolean`). Так что ставь собаку перед `mysql_result (@mysql_result(...))`, чтобы пользователь таких ошибок не видел, но предварительно исправь запрос.

Я бы попробовал

1. Отдельно эту строчку запроса сформировать и вывести посмотреть, передается ли туда вообще этот параметр из переменной `$last_day`
2. Уточнить что в переменной `$last_day` находится, чтоб типы совпадали.
3. Ну и напоследок, но надеюсь, это уже и так сделано: проверить написание названий таблицы и ее существование вообще.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
$query = @mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `visit_everyday` WHERE `time` = '{$last_day}'");

if (!$query)
{
   die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_result($result), 0) == 0){
 //do something...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visit_everyday WHERE time = '$last_day'");
if(mysql_result($result), 0) == 0){
 //do something...
}
```

[mysql_result()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-result.php)

Comment: if(mysql_result($result), 0) == 0){

ЧТО ЭТО???????

Comment: кривой код это